# How can I limit resource allocation among different processes running on CentOS 5 (2.6.18 kernel)?

Tags: linux, migration, centos, virtualization, virtual-machine

I want to limit the CPU, memory, network-bandwidth consumption of different processes running on the same CentOS 5 (2.6.18 kernel) server. And, it is good if I can migrate a process from one server to another. We are using a shared cluster. I do have sudo authority but I am not allowed to modify the kernel. I was looking into light weight virtualization. But LXC is not compatible with our kernel and KVM seems to heavy. Any recommendation? Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose `ionice` and `setrlimit`/`ulimit` would help? Neither of these directly addresses network bandwidth, but they're a lot lighter-weight than virtualization.

Comment: Hi BRPocock, thank you very much for your reply. I will look into ionice and setrlimit/ulimit. I think as long as they can limit the cpu and memory usage, it's fine. Maybe I can integrate HTB with those tools.

Comment: Hi BRPocock, I think setrlimit sends signals when the process reaches its soft limit and kills the process when the hard limit is reached. What I really want is something like light-weight virtual machine, where processes do not need to care about those signals. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the processor, there is a tool, called CPULimit that is available on source forge. Check [this link](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/).

for the memory case, you may take a look at [this link](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40). it is helpful.